How do I maintain URL fragments when using Sphinx and Sphinx-reredirects to handle URL redirects?
I recently restructured a Sphinx documentation project by moving around a lot of files and arranging them into associated folders. This process changed the location urls of the existing documentation causing the old links to return 404s.
I used the sphinx-reredirects extension to handle redirects to the new location of the documentation pages. This works fine for most of the URLs. However, URLs that contain fragments/anchors, for example: an old URL, https://example.com/docs#example1, would redirect to https://example.com/new-location/docs, losing the #example1 in the process. These fragments are very important as a lot of links to the docs scattered accross the internet contain fragments and removing them would cause the links to lose important context.
I have tried intercepting the redirect using JavaScript, but I can't seem to capture the URL that causes the redirect in my code before it happens.
// Function to capture and log the current URL
function logOldUrl() {
  const oldUrl = window.location.href;
  const hash = window.location.hash;
  console.log("Old URL before redirect:", oldUrl, hash);
}

// Add an event listener to capture the URL before unloading the page
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", logOldUrl);

window.onload = logOldUrl;

// Optionally, listen for visibility changes to detect potential navigation changes
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    logOldUrl();
  }
});

logOldUrl();

It keeps logging the new URL. Are there any events that Sphinx-reredirects emits before a redirect happens or are there any other ways to tackle this issue?
